# Good Publishing Tool

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a good publishing tool to write articles. I saw the book  ["Head First Python" from O'Reily Media](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781449382674/?CMP=ILC-hf1st) and found it really interesting, the way they present things in the book.

I am looking to organize my articles in similar fashion. I am looking for a similar publishing tool in Ubuntu or Windows. I would prefer a open source alternative.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 9):

[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) is the most popular open source desktop publishing application, it is available from the software center.

Comment: Thanks, I have just started using scibus and I must say looks very promising for my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

That O'Reilly series of books uses lots of illustration, diagrams and fancy fonts. You need a full-blown *DTP* application for that - only Scribus comes to mind. Chances are O'Reilly use the proprietary InDesign application. For a full book, Scribus might not be powerful enough (although it is worth a try). Something simpler might be accomplished with OpenOffice.org.

Less graphically complex documents can be typeset with LaTeX. With LaTeX, some things - like good-looking type - are easy, but some other things - like pixel-perfect tables - are hard to get right without lots of programming. [This](https://github.com/progit/progit) is an example of a whole book with all the tools required to turn it into a PDF ready to go to the press.

Comment: LaTeX would definitely be my choice. My I think loevborg is overstating difficulties with graphics. The `booktabs` package makes fine-looking tables, following solid typographical rules. I actually think LaTeX's quality is superior not just to Scribus, but Indesign as well for certain kinds of material (especially technical/scientific/mathematical work, but even its plain text paragraph layout algorithm is easily as good as theirs).