# Open-source alternative to Adobe InDesign

Tags: software-recommendation, design

There is some open-source software, similar to Adobe InDesign? It would be awesome if it do exist...

I know all the others like Inkscape, Gimp, etc... but for InDesign i have none.

Could you give me one direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scribus is probably the best alternative to Adobe InDesign right now. Although Inkscape can also do a quite good job. Recently I came across Lucidpress which has a web interface and it seems quite powerful desktop publishing application.

By the way, I maintain a website for open source alternatives to popular software which I update quite frequently. You can check this link for InDesign alternatives:

http://www.opensourcealternative.org/open-source-alternative-indesign/

Answer (score 24):

Try out [*Scribus*](http://www.scribus.net/).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribus):

> Scribus is designed for flexible
>   layout and typesetting and the ability
>   to prepare files for professional
>   quality image setting equipment. It
>   can also create animated and
>   interactive PDF presentations and
>   forms. Example uses include writing
>   small newspapers, brochures,
>   newsletters, posters and books.

You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install scribus
```

Also see the question [Good Publishing Tool](https://askubuntu.com/q/21046/19490) and the thread [Open Source InDesign?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=112641)

Comment: It seems great and very similar to InDesign.. Thnx.

Comment: I second Scribus. Ive created a few PDF brochures with it in the past and they have come out great. Its easy to jump into and learn as you go too.