# How Can I Install New Application in Ubuntu OS System

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install some new applications into my Ubuntu OS System, but I can't find them. Please share your suggestions.

I am trying to install Adobe InDesign.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open-source alternative to Adobe InDesign](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48862/open-source-alternative-to-adobe-indesign)

Answer (score 3):

Adobe has decided that they don't want their InDesign software to run on Linux. Including Ubuntu.

Complain to Adobe, or consider using alternative software.

Comment: Or use Wine - if that's possible for Adobe apps (I have no clue)..

Comment: @Artur Meinild: You can find Wine compatible apps here: https://appdb.winehq.org/, And InDesign Wine ratings here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=755&sClass=application.

Answer (score 0):

**Wine ratings for Adobe InDesign**
can be found here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=755&sClass=application

The best rated version of InDesign, (using Ubuntu 9.04), is InDesign 2.0 (codenamed Annapurna): January 2002. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=1000

Another alternative might be to use VirtualBox running Windows in Ubuntu.